# What is the dimension of the orthogonal complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W$ be the null space of the matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix}1& 0 & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 0& 0 &0 & 1 & 3\\ 0 &1 &3 &0 &2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

What is the dimension of $W^\perp$?

The answer I was given is 4, but I don't know why.

I know the rank of the matrix is 3, so the nullity is 2. The nullity is the dimension of the nullspace, so that is $W$ in this problem.

I also know that $dim(V) = dim(W) + dim(W^\perp)$, but I don't know the dimension of V.

Am I even going in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you switch the second and third row, the matrix become row echelon form, and we can see that the rank of the matrix is $4$ since we have $4$ pivot columns. You should be able to adjust the nullity accordingly.
- Elements of nullspace lives in $\mathbb{R}^5$, $V=\mathbb{R}^5$.